# Por que preciso declarar um tipo dentro do "foreach"?

Tags: java, foreach

Por que em um `foreach` precisamos sempre declarar uma variável.

Exemplo:

```
   for(Pessoa pessoa : pessoas) {
    //qualquer coisa 
   }
```

Em outras palavras, quero saber porque não é possível fazer isso:

```
  Pessoa pessoa;
  for(pessoa : pessoas) {
      //qualquer coisa
  }
```

Comment: [Why is declaration of the variable required inside a for-each loop in java](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6136766/5524514)

Comment: @bfavaretto o foreach do c# também funciona assim, que nem do java. Só não testei se o .NET permite declarar fora.

Comment: Mais um link interessante: http://www.guj.com.br/t/for-foreach-ou-iterator-pq/73747/7

Comment: Se é do GUJ não é interessante :D Só zuando... :P O Vini Godoy não costuma falar besteira, pelo menos deve falar menos que eu :P Em C# há uma discussão para o compilador gerar um código que evita o O(N2) em `foreach` aninhado. Não é algo simples de fazer.

Comment: @bigown não gosto muito do guj, mas por causa dele q referenciei, já achei vários posts dele que me esclareceram muitas duvidas sobre logica e java.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O código

```
ArrayList textos = new ArrayList<String>();
textos.add("texto1");
textos.add("texto2");
for (String t : textos) {
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Na verdade é compilado assim:

```
ArrayList textos = new ArrayList<String>();
textos.add("texto1");
textos.add("texto2");
for (Iterator<String> it = textos.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    String t = it.next();
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

Se colocar a declaração para fora, ficaria como? Assim?

```
    ArrayList textos = new ArrayList<String>();
    textos.add("texto1");
    textos.add("texto2");
    String t = it.next();
    for (Iterator<String> it = textos.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
        System.out.println(t);
    }
```

Tente compilar e veja se dá certo.

O compilador pode ser inteligente de achar um jeito de resolver isto? Pode. Mas preferiam não complicá-lo para pouca e discutível vantagem.

Claro que dá para fazer isto:

```
ArrayList textos = new ArrayList<String>();
textos.add("texto1");
textos.add("texto2");
String t;
for (Iterator<String> it = textos.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
    t = it.next();
    System.out.println(t);
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Syntax/ForEachInternal.java).

Simples, né? Pense em um exemplo mais complexo onde o compilador teria que analisar outros trechos do código para saber se está tudo certo, se não vai afetar nada realizar esta operação.

Outro ponto importante é que o `foreach` foi criado para ir do início ao fim de uma sequência de dados. Foi criado para evitar *bugs* que o programador poderia provocar tentando iterar fora do padrão. Porque você iria querer que um dado específico - o último - escapasse do laço? Só o último precisa poderia ser acessado fora do laço. Se precisar fazer isto, melhor ser explícito e colocar em uma variável. É pouco provável que valha a pena criar uma complicação tão grande no compilador e que mata uma das vantagens do `foreach` para resolver um caso que raramente é usado e sempre pode ser evitado.

No fim, foi apenas uma decisão tomada. Nada impede da linguagem permitir isto. Só não vale o esforço.

Answer (score 6):

A resposta simples: porque [a especificação requer que o valor usado no for-each seja declarado nele](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2).

Elaborando um pouco, [os designers da linguagem decidiram por esse modelo por simplicidade](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html) - esse bloco funciona para a maioria dos casos, e o compilador não precisa se preocupar com a variável "escapando" do laço. Há vários cenários que não funcionam com essa restrição (acessar o valor da variável iterada depois do fim do laço, modificações no iterador, iteração de múltiplas variáveis ao mesmo tempo / em paralelo). Mas quem especificou esta funcionalidade achou que a simplicidade da construção era mais importante que atender a todos os cenários.

Answer (score 3):

Apenas pra complementar, vou colocar o que o [@Sorrow falou no link que @DiegoFelipe postou](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136576/why-is-declaration-of-the-variable-required-inside-a-for-each-loop-in-java/6136766#6136766)

```
 private static void testForEach(ArrayList<String> als) {
  for(String s: als)
    System.out.println(s);
 }

 private static void testIterator(ArrayList<String> als) {
  for(Iterator<String> is = als.iterator(); is.hasNext();) {
   String s = is.next();
   System.out.println(s);
  } 
 }
```

Lá ele diz que ambas iterações apresentam o mesmo Bytecode e que ao que tudo indica a primeira opção é (ou aparenta ser) apenas uma forma de  Syntactic Sugar.