# Acessar itens de uma pilha usando for

Tags: java, for

Estou tentando acessar uma posição a frente na pilha para fazer uma comparação, mas não esta dando certo e não consegui entender esse `for`.

Código

```
for ( String UmToken : PilhaTokens) 
{
    System.out.println(UmToken);
}
```

Comparação que eu queria fazer

```
for ( String UmToken : PilhaTokens) 
{
     if(listaReserva.contains(UmToken) && listaOperadores.contains(UmToken+1))
     {
         System.out.println("Variavel com nome de Palavra Reservada");

     }
}
```

Alguém sabe me indicar algo que explique o for, ou me sugerir algo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Este tipo de laço é conhecido  como `foreach` e como pode ser visto [nesta resposta do @Maniero](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/111196/28595), ele foi feito para percorrer do inicio ao fim uma sequência de dados. Normalmente é usado para percorrer uma lista, onde o índice não é tão importante para o que precisa ser feito na iterações(como apenas exibir itens em sequencia).

Como alternativa ao problema apresentado, você pode usa o `for` tradicional, iniciando o indice de 1 até o final, assim, você consegue efetuar a comparação de forma mais "elegante", comparando o atual item com o anterior. Veja um exemplo:

```
String[] array = {"a","b","c","d"};

    for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
        System.out.print("Valor anterior: " + array[i-1]);
        System.out.print(" - ");
        System.out.println("Valor atual: " + array[i]);
    }
```

Saida:

> Valor anterior: a - Valor atual: b
>   Valor anterior: b - Valor atual: c
>   Valor anterior: c - Valor atual: d

Veja funcionando no [**IDEONE**](http://ideone.com/BRt5TM).

Adaptando ao seu código, ficaria desta forma:

```
for(int i = 1; i < PilhaTokens.size(); i++){
  if(listaReserva.contains(PilhaToken.get(i)) &&  
     listaOperadores.contains(PilhaToken.get(i-1))){
     System.out.println("Variavel com nome de Palavra Reservada");
   }
}
```

Comment: No linguajar do Java, ele se chama _Enhanced For_ ou "For melhorado".

Comment: @PabloAlmeida pra não passar a idéia de que o nome era `foreach`, modifiquei o texto. Como a outra resposta já deu uma explicação, eu somente complementei com um exemplo pra solucionar o problema da pergunta.

Comment: Não consigo usar length =/ já tentei da erro, eu declarei "PilhaTokens = new Stack<String>();"

Comment: @OMaths no seu caso, Stack é uma classe de Collections, substitua o `length` por `size()`, e ao inves de `PilhaTokens[i]`, use `PilhaTokens.get(i)`

Comment: @DiegoF Muuito Obrigado meesmo! sério! kkk não tem noção como já tinha cansado de procurar isso! xD

Answer (score 4):

OMaths,

O esse "for" se chama "foreach", ele server para percorrer todo o seu objeto do inicio até o fim. Você acessa o valor do seu objeto percorrido pela "variável" que você criou.

```
for ( String UmToken : PilhaTokens) 
{
    System.out.println(UmToken);
}
```

PilhaTokens = Lista de String
UmToken = variável
String = tipo da Lista

Segue uma referencia mais didática.
http://www.javaprogressivo.net/2012/09/o-laco-for-para-arrays.html

Espero ter ajudado!