# Laço for a partir do index 1 array java

Tags: java, array, for

Tenho uma função que faz um laço for em um array de String.
Preciso que o laço inicie a partir do `index[1]` desse array. 
Porém não estou conseguindo.

```
 String arquivo[] = arquivoDecodificado.split("\r\n|\r|\n");
         for(String linha: arquivo ) {
            String[] linhaQuebrada= linha.split(";");
            Pessoas idPessoa = pessoasService.buscarPessoaComCnpj(linhaQuebrada[0],idEntidade);
            operadoraCart.setEntidade(ent);
            operadoraCart.setPessoa(idPessoa);
            operadoraCartaoService.cadastrar(operadoraCart);

         }
```

Preciso que ele comece o laço a partir de `arquivo[1]`

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Acessar itens de uma pilha usando for](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122395/acessar-itens-de-uma-pilha-usando-for)

Comment: Com o `foreach`, você não tem controle do índice num `array`. Melhor usar o bom e velho `for` nesse caso.

Comment: @StatelessDev  verdade !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Acredito que poderia fazer assim:

```
 String arquivo[] = arquivoDecodificado.split("\r\n|\r|\n");

         for(int i = 1; i < arquivo.length; ++i ) {
            String[] linhaQuebrada= arquivo[i].split(";");
            Pessoas idPessoa = pessoasService.buscarPessoaComCnpj(linhaQuebrada[0],idEntidade);
            operadoraCart.setEntidade(ent);
            operadoraCart.setPessoa(idPessoa);
            operadoraCartaoService.cadastrar(operadoraCart);

         }
```